# Editing and appending to a .bat file depending on file name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to figure out how to make a script that can edit a .bat file and save it under a different name.

example:

Lets say I have a file named 'qwerty'
I'm looking to create a .bat that contains
'scriptscriptscipt FILENAME' and saves it as FILENAME.bat

the edit would then change the contents to 'scriptscriptscript qwerty' and save it as qwerty.bat

Something along these lines would help greatly cut down the time on manually editing about 6000 files, any help appreciated!

EDIT:
extra example

I have a file named '5c48170170623084298182d583d09964'

the script in my .txt file reads:
'disunity extract '

I wish to change the file to read:
'disunity extract 5c48170170623084298182d583d09964'

and save the file as 5c48170170623084298182d583d09964.bat

Comment: Please provide an example

Comment: I'll add the example to the main post @unknownoctopus

Comment: yeah I have microsoft visual C++ 2013 on here

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `powershell` script, oh test it for few files,

```
$a = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.bat | % { 
$d = $_
$b = (Get-Content $d) | %{ if($_.contains("extract")) { $_ }}
if ( ![String]::IsNullOrEmpty($b) ) {
    $c = $b.Split(" ")
    $1 = [array]::indexof($c, "extract ")
    Write-Host $c[$1+1]
    copy $d ("out\"+ ($c[$1+1]+ ".bat")
  }
}
```